# $cos^2$ identity where $sin^2$ has a coefficient

Tags: trigonometry

Does $1-\lambda^2 \times \sin^2\ = \lambda^2 \times \cos^2$ ? I'm trying to do Von Neumann analysis for convergence and I'm struggling to reduce the LHS under a square root.

Comment: $λ^2\cos^2 = λ^2 - λ^2\sin^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Only if $\lambda=\pm1$. Otherwise, generally what we have is
$$\lambda^2-\lambda^2\cdot\sin^2=\lambda^2\cdot\cos^2\,.$$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there any kind of simplification that's available for my case? My problem specifically is an inequality:

$\sqrt(1-\lambda^2 *\sin^2) \leq 1$

Comment: Hint: if $0 \le t \le 1$, $\sqrt{1-t} \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The trig identity is $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$. You can of course multiply this entire equation by a constant, say, $\lambda^2$, but that only gives you

$$\lambda^2*\sin^2x+\lambda^2*\cos^2x = \lambda^2.$$

(Unless $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$, of course.)